# How to SELECT a single record in table X with the largest value for X.a WHERE values for fields X.b & X.c are specified

Tags: openedge, progress-db

I am using the following query to obtain the current component serial number (`tr_sim_sn`) installed on the host device (`tr_host_sn`) from the most recent record in a transaction history table (`PUB.tr_hist`)

```
SELECT tr_sim_sn FROM PUB.tr_hist   
WHERE tr_trnsactn_nbr = (SELECT max(tr_trnsactn_nbr) 
                 FROM PUB.tr_hist 
                 WHERE tr_domain = 'vattal_us' 
                 AND tr_lot = '99524136' 
                 AND tr_part = '6684112-001')
```

The actual table has ~190 million records. The excerpt below contains only a few sample records, and only fields relevant to the search to illustrate the query above:

```
tr_sim_sn      |tr_host_sn* |tr_host_pn     |tr_domain  |tr_trnsactn_nbr |tr_qty_loc
_______________|____________|_______________|___________|________________|___________
...            |               
356136072015140|99524135    |6684112-000    |vattal_us  |178415271       |-1.0000000000
356136072015458|99524136    |6684112-001    |vattal_us  |178424418       |-1.0000000000
356136072015458|99524136    |6684112-001    |vattal_us  |178628048       |1.0000000000
356136072015050|99524136    |6684112-001    |vattal_us  |178628051       |-1.0000000000
356136072015836|99524137    |6684112-005    |vattal_us  |178645337       |-1.0000000000
...
```

> `*` = key field

The excerpt illustrates multiple occurrences of `tr_trnsactn_nbr` for a single value of  `tr_host_sn`.  The largest value for `tr_trnsactn_nbr` corresponds to the current `tr_sim_sn` installed within `tr_host_sn`.

This query works, but it is very slow, ~8minutes.

I would appreciate suggestions to improve or refactor this query to improve its speed.

Comment: Are you using the  built-in SQL-89 or the external SQL-92 engine?  You are not prefacing the tables with "PUB." so I suspect SQL-89 which would mean that your optimizations are subject to the same rules as the 4gl engine. Those rules are static compile time evaluations of index selection within the WHERE clause. But if you are using the the SQL-92 engine a cost based optimizer applies and the is sensitive to when you last ran UPDATE STATISTICS.

Comment: @TomBascom - I am away from the office for now, but tomorrow I will Google how to best determine what version, and get back to you.  Thanks.

Comment: @TomBascom - regarding not prefacing table with `PUB`,... actually the real queries do use `PUB` prefixes.   Sorry for the confusion on that point.  I was attempting to shorten everything for readability, and did not realize the significance of the `PUB` prefix would have.  I have edited the post to fix that mistake.  ( I am a noob with everything database, in particular using OpenEdge SQL.)

Comment: @TomBascom - ...Also, I just learned from one of our database admins that our implementation uses an external SQL-92 engine, and he explained that it starts a separate broker for just for SQL as well as providing ODBC connection to extract reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this as a response to my request for an improved query.

As it turns out, the following syntax features two distinct features that greatly improved the speed of the query.  One is to include `tr_domain` search criteria in both main and nested portions of the query.  Second is to narrow the search by increasing the number of search criteria, which in the following are all included in the nested section of the syntax:

```
SELECT tr_sim_sn, 
FROM  PUB.tr_hist 
WHERE tr_domain = 'vattal_us' 
  AND tr_trnsactn_nbr IN (
      SELECT MAX(tr_trnsactn_nbr) 
      FROM   PUB.tr_hist 
      WHERE tr_domain  = 'vattal_us' 
        AND tr_part    = '6684112-001' 
        AND tr_lot     = '99524136' 
        AND tr_type    = 'ISS-WO' 
        AND tr_qty_loc < 0)
```

This syntax results in ~0.5s response time.  (credit to my colleague, Daniel V.)

To be fair, this query uses criteria outside the originally stated parameters that were included in the original post, making it difficult to impossible for others to attempt a reasonable answer.  This omission was not on purpose of course, rather due to being fairly new to fundamentals of good query design. This query in part is a result of learning that when too-few or non-indexed fields are used as search criteria in a large table, it is sometimes helpful to narrow the search by increasing the number of search criteria items.  The original had 3, this one has 5.

Answer (score 1):

Check with your admins to determine when they last updated the SQL statistics. If the answer is "we don't know" or "never" then you might want to ask them to run the following 4gl program which will create a SQL script to accomplish that:

```
/* genUpdateSQL.p
 *
 * mpro dbName -p util/genUpdateSQL.p -param "tmp/updSQLstats.sql"
 *
 * sqlexp -user userName -password passWord -db dnName -S servicePort -infile tmp/updSQLstats.sql -outfile tmp/updSQLtats.log
 *
 */

output to value( ( if session:parameter <> "" then session:parameter else "updSQLstats.sql" )).

for each _file no-lock where _hidden = no:

  put unformatted
     "UPDATE TABLE STATISTICS AND INDEX STATISTICS AND ALL COLUMN STATISTICS FOR PUB."
     '"' _file._file-name '"' ";"
    skip
  .
  put unformatted "commit work;" skip.

end.

output close.

return.
```

This will generate a script that updates statistics for all table and all indexes. You could edit the output to only update the tables and indexes that are part of this query if you want.

Also, if the admins are nervous they could, of course, try this on a test db or a restored backup before implementing in a production environment.

Comment: Thank you Tom. Is it your assertion then that updating statistics for all tables and indexes (or just those specific to my query) will significantly reduce query times?  (if so, can you throw out a wag of by what percentage?)

Comment: I cannot guarantee that it will. But the optimizer has no chance at all if it has no statistics to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.  I have begun taking your suggested questions/suggestions to our IT people.  Laughingly you nailed their response: 'we don't know`, but at least the _we_ is checking with others who may know.